# how to convert readable date to unix-timestamp?

Tags: excel, notepad++, unix-timestamp

I am looking for a function in excel to convert bulk readable date to #unix #timestamp.(with +3 GMT) offset.

I tried many over the net but it seems to be wrong because I have example of the correct time as bellow:

Date="**2014-06-20T22:05:23**"  DateLong="**1403291123000**"

I don't know which part I am missing.

Thanks,
Mahmood

Comment: I don't completely understand your question, but Unix time is the number of seconds since 1/1/1970.  So once you have the time you'd like to convert as an Excel time, subtract 1/1/1970 and multiply by 86,400.  Excel stores dates and times as days and fractions of a day, and there are 86,400 seconds in a day.

Answer (score 0):

Try this->

```
NSString * stringDate = @"2014-06-20T22:05:23";
NSDateFormatter * formater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formater setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate * date = [formater dateFromString:stringDate];
NSUInteger timestamp = [date timeIntervalSince1970];
NSLog(@"%d", timestamp);
```

Log - 1403291123

I hope it help you.

Comment: Thanks, but I think its not correct, as I got the answer in the example "1403291123000"

Comment: get my answer and multiply 1000, 1403291123 (000)